# Value shrink while converting Double to Bigdecimal

Tags: java

My problem while I am converting Double to BigDecimal I am loosing original value.
My requirement like input would be  like Double val = 10435383974769502920d and want to convert like 10435.383974769502920 but getting below output.
I have tried with Double BigDecimal..but no success

```
Double val = 10435383974769502920d;
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(val).movePointLeft(15));

output : 10435.383974769502
```

Comment: My problem is I am dealing with signals and watts so cant change value at any cost...

Comment: Its not same as u suggested they ware using decimal value however I want to convert to decimal a non decimal value, while converting its limiting somehow  till 18 digit only

Answer (score 2):

```
Double val = 10435383974769502920d;
```

A double simply can't hold that many digits. Doubles are limited to ~15 decimal digits of precision. It's not `BigDecimal` that's losing the extra digits; it's the double you're starting with.

```
>>> System.out.printf("%f\n", 10435383974769502920d);
10435383974769502000.000000
```

Construct the `BigDecimal` with a string to avoid losing precision.

```
String val = "10435383974769502920";
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(val).movePointLeft(15));
```

Comment: Good answer - want to add that you don’t need movePointLeft, you can just put the decimal point at the right place in the input string to BigDecimal

Comment: Erwin I have tried to put . in String it self its working as well but in code review..I have to remove that